# Jquery, How to Clone Node on certain keydown and remove the Clone on other certain keydown, but not removing the parent node

Tags: jquery

I try to clone node and remove the clone with certain keys (one for clone, and the other for remove). It's work, but it can remove the parent node too, which is I don't want that. So how to remove only the child nodes?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
    input.in {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="number" id="in" class="in">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).keydown(function(x) {
        if (x.which === 40) {
            var clone = $('#in').clone();
            $('#in').after(clone);
        }
        if (x.which === 38) {
            $('#in').remove(clone);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: btw, 40 is "down key" and 38 is "up key"

Comment: there is no parent code for `<input type="number" id="in" class="in">` which parent node you talking about?

Comment: I mean the first input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition to check if it's last input. Try something like:

```
<script>
    $(document).keydown(function(x) {
        if (x.which === 40) {
            var clone = $('#in').clone();
            $('#in').after(clone);
        }
        if (x.which === 38) {
            if ($('.in').length > 1) {
                $('#in').remove(clone);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

`NOTE`: Try to change the logic because when you clone the node the `id` will be same on every node, which isn't a good practice. You should avoid using duplicates for ID

Comment: Aah,, so definite the class is useful for the function too? thank you!

Comment: @HudoyoDanumurti yes just try to use class instead of id.